# Inertia tensor rotation to a new coordinate system

Tags: python, matrix, coordinates, physics

I have the moments of inertia for some arbitrary body, say:

```
inertia_tensor = np.array([
    [ 1,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  2,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  3]
])
```

This inertia tensor was calculated in a given coordinate system, we'll call that "A". I have another coordinate system that was rotated about the origin of A to a new position, we'll call that "B". I would like to calculate what the inertia tensor would be in B.

From what I've gathered, the calculation is simple, but I'm failing to grasp the final output should be. I know the moments of inertia should be positive, so I take the absolute value of them, but do I just leave the products of inertia as is? I'm referencing Eq. 15 on page 9 for reference (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec26.pdf)

I'm using python, so I'll go ahead and show my code interpretation

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

rot_matrix = R.from_euler('X', [-90], degrees=True).as_matrix()
rotated = np.matmul(rot_matrix, np.matmul(inertia_tensor, rot_matrix.T))

for i in range(len(rotated)):
    rotated[i, i] = abs(rotated[i, i])
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ① belongs to engineering or physics stackexchange sites and ② it's not even a question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor_of_rotation